# How to show only one price when the price range doesn't change?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

By default WooCommerce shows minimum and maximum price values for **grouped products**. However, it still shows range of price when the range doesn't exist (e.g. $55 - $55). This is very ambiguous and unnecessary.

Is it possible to hide the dash and higher value when the minimum and maximum prices are the same?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know which part of code is responsible for the mentioned prices range, but I found the following condition in the git and it seems that there's already a condition for the case where `min` equals `max` - https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/68974655d6bbaa0e253655709256dc8f18c3219f/includes/class-wc-product-grouped.php#L188

Comment: That's weird. The problem was solved by WC devs for variable products but grouped products were ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be added to functions.php of your theme

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
$price = '';

if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) $price .= '<span class="from">' . _x('From', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';
$price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());
if ( $product->max_variation_price && $product->max_variation_price !== $product->min_variation_price ) {
$price .= '<span class="to"> ' . _x('to', 'max_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';

$price .= woocommerce_price($product->max_variation_price);
}

return $price;
}
```

Comment: This answer references variable products, while the original question was about grouped products. `woocommerce_grouped_price_html` or the catchall `woocommerce_get_price_html` would be the target filters.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. The feature I wanted is present by default but for some reason the paid plugin "WooCommerce Prices By User Role" turned it off. It came back when I turned the plugin off.